# PyDev auto import with PyQt4

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt, pydev

In PyDev I can type a class name, press Control + 1 and select from the dropdown menu the "import XY" entry and Pydev will automatically add an import statement for me. This works with classes coming from any .py module. But it does not work with PyQt4, although I added PyQt4 to the forced builtins. Has someone gotten this to work?

Doing it the reverse way works:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
QtCore.[autocomplete works!]
```

Using Python 2.6.8, PyQt 4.8.3, Eclipse 3.7 and Pydev 2.6 on Windows XP 64 SP 2. All packages are installed with the standard distribution installer.

Comment: Is PyQt4 in your installation's site-packages?

Comment: Yes, it is. I also added some environment information to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same issue as in this question and it was answered by the plugin's author:

[PyDev organize imports PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639522/pydev-organize-imports-pyqt4)