# PyDev organize imports PyQt4

Tags: python, eclipse, pyqt, pyqt4, pydev

I am using PyQt4 and would like to be able to use "Organize Imports", so I can just write something like:

QPixmap(":/filename.png")

and hit Ctrl+Shift+F (Organize Imports) and this is added:

from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap

But this does not work for me.

My question is: Is this feature available? How can I activate it?

Note: The default auto-complete works with PyQt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works up to a level... PyDev can do what you just described (although there's a typo there: the shortcut is actually Ctrl+Shift+O), but only for source modules (if you're going to the internal tokens level). In the case of PyQt4, it only goes to the module level.

So, you could do:

QtGui and it'd show PyQt4.QtGui, but it doesn't go on to analyze tokens to suggest inside QtGui (although it'll suggest tokens inside QtGui after you have the PyQt4.QtGui import already).

There's an issue reported at the tracker for that already: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/176 (although it's not very high in the priority list as it still does not have any votes).

A note: code-completion on the QtGui would already suggest that option or you could just do a Ctrl+1 in that same line to be offered the option to add the import (without having to resort to doing Ctrl+Shift+O).